# How to get MessageBodyWriter to work with a HashMap using RestEasy and Tomcat?

Tags: java, jaxb, hashmap, resteasy, concurrenthashmap

I am developing a JAX-RS webservice using RestEasy 2.2.2 to be deployed to Tomcat 7. The service returns (should return) XML through the use of JAXB. Returned XML should contain representations of ConcurrentHashMap similar to how it is used in the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ItemCollection 
{
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Item> items;

    public ItemCollection()
    {
        items = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, item>();
        // fill the map
    }
}
```

The `Item` class also contains a `ConcurrentHashMap` that needs to be serialized to XML.

This is the resource class:

```
@Path("/items")
public class ItemResource 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ItemCollection getAllItems() 
    {
        // get itemManager
        return itemManager.getItems(); // ItemManager holds an instance of ItemCollection
    }
}
```

This code runs, but produces an XML with no content:

```
<items>
    <item/>
</items>
```

What I am trying to get as an output is something like:

```
<items>
    <item id="...">
        <data>...</data>
        <otheritems>
            <otheritem id="...">
                <someotherdata>...</someotherdata>
            </otheritem>
        </otheritems>
    </item>
    <item id="...">
        <data>...</data>
        <otheritems>
            <otheritem id="...">
                <someotherdata>...</someotherdata>
            </otheritem>
            <otheritem id="...">
                <someotherdata>...</someotherdata>
            </otheritem>
            <otheritem id="...">
                <someotherdata>...</someotherdata>
            </otheritem>
        </otheritems>
    </item>
</items>
```

I found out that a `MessageBodyWriter` implementation is required where builtin functionality is not sufficient. I tried to come up with a `MessageBodyWriter` implementation to marshal the `ConcurrentHashMap`, but I have not been able to get it working so far (i.e. I can get the code being called, but it stops with various exceptions).

It seems I do not quite grasp how `MessageBodyWriter` (and `MessageBodyReader`) interfaces should be implemented and used. I have Bill Burke's "RESTful Java with JAX-RS" book. It is very useful in terms of helping design JAX-RS services but I could not find enough details about the `MessageBodyWriter` functionality in the related section. My internet searches did not yield anything that could guide me in the right direction, either.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me in figuring out how to implement the `MessageBodyWriter` (and `MessageBodyReader`) interfaces properly. I do not know if I am missing an annotation, misplacing one or whether I need a completely new approach.

Thanks in advance for helping.

**EDIT:**

Modifying the code to following gets me halfway there:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ItemCollection 
{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Item> items;

    public ItemCollection()
    {
        items = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, item>();
        // fill the map
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public Collection<Item> getItems()
    {
        return items.values();
    }
}
```

This generates the XML that I need (sample included above). However, this code does not work when it comes to unmarshalling. I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:221)
  com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:290)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:254)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:106)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:195)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:507)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:145)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:142)
javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:151)
javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:169)
// ... the rest
```

I assume the reason is the lack of a "proper setter" so that the unmarshaller does not try to add items into a `Collection` but I do not know how that setter would look like. If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2:**

BTW, I have seen Chris' reply where he suggests using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. I have tried the suggestion and it gets me close to the XML I need. However, the XML I get using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter has an extra level in it (`<class><items><item>` instead of `<items><item>` --- as seen in my examples, I have the `ConcurrentHashMap` instances as a member variable of a class). I also can't seem to change the element name of the individual map items (they are always called "item").

These are not big problems and I can make the necessary changes and live with them if necessary. If possible, however, I would like to not have them in the first place. For educational purposes, I would also like to understand why the code in EDIT 1 does not work for unmarshalling (and how to fix it, if possible).

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to mix JAXB with your MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter. You have a JAXB object so you do not really want RestEasy to do all of the serialization using your MessageBodyWriter as it would not take into account your JAXB objects. You could do it this way, but you would need to serialize the rest of your object model too.

The MessageBodyReader/Writer is geared for working with Streams which is probably why it did not make much sense. It makes no assumptions that you are going to XML.

What you probably want to do is create an JAXB XmlJavaTypeAdapter for the map and let JAXB do the XML creation. You can find more information on the JavaDoc page:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html

I did find one good post on this over the Metro mailing list [here](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/Does-JAXB-2-0-support-Map-td1058084.html). This code should give you what you want. The context was around JAX-WS but you are looking specifically for the JAXB annotation to do a custom binding.

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class Root 
{ 
  private String name; 
  private int    junk; 

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class) 
  private Map<String, Boolean> lights; 

  public Root() 
  { 
    name = ""; junk = 0; lights = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); 
  } 

  public void   setName(String newName)  { name = newName; } 
  public String getName()                { return name; } 

  public void setJunk(int newJunk)  { junk = newJunk; } 
  public int  getJunk()             { return junk; } 

  public void turnLightOn(String lightName)   { lights.put(lightName, true); } 
  public void turnLightOff(String lightName)  { lights.put(lightName, false); } 
} 

class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElements[], Map<String, Boolean>> 
{ 
  public MapElements[] marshal(Map<String, Boolean> arg0) throws Exception 
  { 
    MapElements[] mapElements = new MapElements[arg0.size()]; 

    int i = 0; 
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : arg0.entrySet()) 
      mapElements[i++] = new MapElements(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 

    return mapElements; 
  } 

  public Map<String, Boolean> unmarshal(MapElements[] arg0) throws Exception 
  { 
    Map<String,Boolean> r = new HashMap<String,Boolean>(); 
    for(MapElements mapelement : arg0) 
      r.put(mapelement.key, mapelement.value); 
    return r; 
  } 
} 

class MapElements 
{ 
  @XmlElement public String  key; 
  @XmlElement public Boolean value; 

  private MapElements() {} //Required by JAXB 

  public MapElements(String key, Boolean value) 
  { 
    this.key   = key; 
    this.value = value; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this detailed response. I tried it and it gets me near the XML that I need. I bumped into couple issues while implementing the adapter and I edited my post to include them. I would appreciate if you could take a quick look and see if you could suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` method works OK in that it allows JAXB do the serialization and back. However, it does not give me the XML that I need. I thought that would not matter too much, but at the end it turned out that I need to get the XML in that form.

The XML I get using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` has an extra level in it (similar to `<collection><mapitem><item><mapitem><item>` instead of `<collection><item><item>`). I found a post on a forum (I will add the link if I can find it again) that explains this issue and indicates that in order to get this type of XML, JAXB needs to see a collection, rather than a map.

So, with the hope that it will be useful to others, here's what I did:

First, I defined this interface:

```
public interface MyCollectionInterface
{
    public String getItemId();
}
```

Then I modified the items to be put in the collection as follows:

```
public class CollectionItem implements MyCollectionInterface
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id; // This was already a class member

    @Override
    public String getItemId() 
    {
        return id; 
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a known way to get the key to be used with the `HashMap`.

Then came the declaration for `MyCollection`

```
public class MyCollection<E extends MyCollectionInterface> extends AbstractSet<E>
{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, E> items;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        items = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, E>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e)
    {
        return items.putIfAbsent(e.getItemId(), e) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() 
    {
        return items.values().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
        return items.size();
    }

    // other functionality as needed
}
```

Now, modifying the code to the following form puts everything into place:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="items")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ItemCollection 
{
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private MyDictionary<CollectionItem> items;

    public ItemCollection()
    {
        items = new MyDictionary<CollectionItem>();
    }
}
```

This produces the XML I was after (see my original post for an example).